# How to enable Eclipse Code Assistant for PHP?

Tags: php, eclipse

I have been programming C# on Visual Studio for a while and now that I am back at Eclipse + PHP I am missing the great code assistant tool. Well, I tried to enable it from everywhere and it shows up -- **partially**.

This is what I want to see:

[image]

I do see the left side of the assistant, but for some reason I do not see the right side -- which is the more useful part of the two!

Comment: this should show by default. Please go to Window > Preferences and put "assist" in the search box of the Preference panel. Then check your settings if there is anything that you'd need to enable. Also, make sure PDT is properly installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should download and install another Eclipse (if you have a J2EE installed with PHP PDT)

http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-php-developers/heliossr1

This one is special for PHP and works lot better than J2EE + PHP and you'll have this feature by default.